# Are Ionic Native Plugins not available in Ionic capacitor electron desktop apps?

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, electron, ionic-native, capacitor

I need to use In App Purchase 2 Ionic native plugin in an electron desktop app. I've installed it normally and added it in app.module providers, and provided it in the component where needed.

When I `console.log` the plugin object, it returns an object with all values set to null as if it's not initialized.

Checked other Ionic Native plugins and happens same behavior.

How may I use them in ionic capacitor electron desktop app? Or how may I implement In app purchase?

Comment: Ionic native plugins are based on cordova plugins, which do not work in a browser. So this plugin will not work your electron app. You will have to find another way to implement this. There is a plugin `under development` for Capacitor https://github.com/capacitor-community/in-app-purchases

Comment: @ChetanBansal Thank you for the answer. That's what I thought... I also found [In App purchases](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/in-app-purchases) where there is a guide on how to use that capacitor plugin, will give a try. I expected not needing to change my actual code using the native plugin, working on Android and ios, but... Thanks!

Comment: @ChetanBansal  As you said the Capacitor plugin is under development and can't use it. Thanks anyway! Haven't found the way to implement this in electron desktop app.